# How can I Type the expression (x+3)/((x^2)-3x+2) into MATLAB. I keep getting errors

Tags: matlab

(x+3)/((x^2)-3x+2)

The variable is x=1

I enter this code as is, and get the error that

```
x^2-3x+2
  |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Comment: Replace `3x` by `3*x`. This _very basic_ Matlab. I'm voting your question down

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is way too basic. According to [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how you do it.

```
x^2-3*x+2
```